# reorder dendrogram

Tags: r

I want to reorder a dendrogram with reorder.dendrogram, but can not bend my head around how to set the parameters.

The dendrogram has one "outlier" branch, which I want to move to the other side.

I can do that by this cut/merge calls, but surely it is possible with reorder?

Here is the dendrogram:

```
tdro <- structure(list(structure(9L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "leaf1", leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
structure(list(structure(list(structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(15L, label = "leaf2", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
    structure(14L, label = "leaf3", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 24.8381484584436, class = "dendrogram"), 
    structure(list(structure(13L, label = "leaf4", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
        structure(12L, label = "leaf5", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 24.3975287023022, class = "dendrogram")), members = 4L, midpoint = 1.5, height = 33.1101361501252, class = "dendrogram"), 
    structure(list(structure(10L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "leaf6", leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
        structure(list(structure(11L, label = "leaf7", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
            structure(8L, label = "leaf8", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 30.9363490461899, class = "dendrogram")), members = 3L, midpoint = 0.75, height = 32.3912839969328, class = "dendrogram")), members = 7L, midpoint = 3.125, height = 36.9011152635297, class = "dendrogram"), 
    structure(list(structure(5L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "leaf9", leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
        structure(list(structure(list(structure(4L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "leaf10", leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
            structure(list(structure(2L, label = "leaf11", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
              structure(6L, label = "leaf12", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 20.537001267289, class = "dendrogram")), members = 3L, midpoint = 0.75, height = 27.9153607968991, class = "dendrogram"), 
            structure(list(structure(list(structure(7L, label = "leaf13", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram"), 
              structure(3L, label = "leaf14", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 19.3278637150999, class = "dendrogram"), 
              structure(1L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "leaf15", leaf = TRUE, class = "dendrogram")), members = 3L, midpoint = 1.25, height = 27.6624008548179, class = "dendrogram")), members = 6L, midpoint = 2.5, height = 30.8706298846279, class = "dendrogram")), members = 7L, midpoint = 1.75, height = 41.426993488228, class = "dendrogram")), members = 14L, midpoint = 5.9375, height = 41.7600747862578, class = "dendrogram")), members = 15L, midpoint = 3.46875, height = 66.2893195420674, class = "dendrogram")
plot(tdro)
```

Here is what I am after:

```
ddr_cut <- cut(tdro, 50)
want_tdro <- merge(ddr_cut$lower[[2]],
                   ddr_cut$lower[[1]],
                   height=attr(ddr_cut$upper, "height"))
plot(want_tdro)
```

The question is, how should the following call look like:

```
plot(reorder(tdro, c(15,1:14)))
```

so that it becomes `want_tdro`?  And **why**?

Comment: Strange, I don't get it either; I reason that `plot(reorder(tdro, c(15:1)))` would do it but the ordering is wrong in two places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weights that you provide to the `reorder.dendrogram()` function must be in the same order that the original data were used to build the dendrogram.  This is not necessarily the same order as the leaves as you've labeled them (`"leaf1"` to `"leaf15"`).  You can check the underlying order by using the simplest weights, `1:15`, and then looking at the values assigned to each leaf.

```
tdro2 <- reorder(tdro, 1:15, mean)
str(tdro2)
```

If you look at the output from the `str()` function, the reported values correspond to the simple weights we assigned.  From this, we deduce that underlying order of the data is **leaf15, leaf11, leaf14, leaf10, leaf9, leaf12, leaf13, leaf8, leaf1, leaf6, leaf7, leaf5, leaf4, leaf3, leaf2.**

Since you want the order of the leaves to be leaf2-leaf15, leaf1, you should provide weight 1 for leaf2, weight 2 for leaf3, ..., weight 14 for leaf15, and weight 15 for leaf1, but you must provide these weights in the underlying order of the leaves, like this:

```
tdro3 <- reorder(tdro, c(14, 10, 13, 9:8, 11:12, 7, 15, 5:6, 4:1), mean)
plot(tdro3)
```